# asyncsocket accepts socket but doesn't connect to host

Tags: objective-c, cocoaasyncsocket

I've just started running (what I thought was) a basic [asyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) in my objective-c app and I'm getting the didAcceptNewSocket: message when connecting with telnet, but then I'm abruptly disconnected ("Connection closed by foreign host") without reaching the didConnectToHost: message. It works fine in the example and I've tried to replicate everything I see there to no avail.

Is there some simple pitfall I should be avoiding? Any other way I can debug this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I was using the *wrong* delegate methods copied/pasted from some other site. Always check your headers!

Comment: I am having the same issue but I copy and pasted my methods from the header files so I doubt it is that.  Do you know any other reason why this might be happening?